# How to stop a duplicated audio source playing in chrome

Tags: css, html

To play audio across multiple browsers I've added the following code. But in Chrome I've noticed that the music is playing twice and causing an echo effect. How do I change my code to avoid this so Chrome only knows to play one of the files?

```
<!--Plays music on page load!-->

<audio autoplay><source src="music/tune.mp3"></audio> 
<audio autoplay><source src="music/tune.ogg"></audio> 

<!--Music ends!-->
```

Live site here http://crea8tion.com/ChristmasMessage/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put multiple sources within the same `<audio>` tag.

```
<audio autoplay>
  <source src="music/tune.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source src="music/tune.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```